# Unable to extract specific field from Json response

Tags: c#

I used to simply populate the list of EmployeeIds from the following the Json response:

```
{\r\n \"EmployeeId\": [\r\n  201812345,\r\n 201812346,\r\n 201812347, \r\n}
```

into my collection by

```
var resultSet = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<EmployeeIds>();
```

However recently the server response has changed to:

```
{
 "httpStatus": 200,
 "queryID": "getIds",
 "statustext": [
 "ResultCode: OK"
 ],
"rowsReturned": 228,
"dataset": "[\r\n {\r\n  \"EmployeeId\": 20181234\r\n  }, \r\n {\r\n  
\"EmployeeId\": 20181234\r\n  },\r\n {\r\n  \"EmployeeId\": 20181234\r\n 
}\r\n]"
}
```

I am now unable to extract the EmployeeId values from this Json. I have tried to deserializing the response by:

```
var jsonresult=await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var deserializedjsonobject = JObject.Parse(jsonResult);
var Ids= deserializedjsonobject["dataset"]
```

but the value  results for ids  is always:

```
"[\r\n {\r\n  \"EmployeeId\": 20181234\r\n  }, \r\n {\r\n \"EmployeeId\": 20181234\r\n  },\r\n {\r\n  \"EmployeeId\": 20181234\r\n }\r\n]
```

Thanks

Comment: are the `\r\n` actually in there as text or not? I really can't tell. Can you remove those from your examples if they're not actually part of the string? What you're doing seems fine

Comment: Alas, their JSON is terrible (since `dataset` contains a `string`, not an array). You will likely need to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EmployeeId>>` on `Ids`.

Comment: @mjwills Containing a json string is not a terrible thing. It depends on the situation. It allows the general structure to remain the same while allowing you to pass through custom data. I've used this setup in real systems

Comment: @JoePhillips Having JSON embedded in a string is very rarely a good thing (and by very rarely I mean almost never). The exact same benefits you mention could occur if the JSON was **not** inside a string (since it is JSON - you can add any extra custom properties etc very easily in JSON since it isn't typed). _Unless you want to allow it to **sometimes** be JSON, and **sometimes** not - which I would argue is not a great API design (aka terrible)._

Comment: @mjwills Unless you're going to make a different endpoint for literally every single possible "shape" of data, you have no other choice. The example in this case makes it seem like the data is really a string. It doesn't even have to be json. It depends on the result, endpoint, status, etc, as to what gets returned.

Comment: Thanks @JoePhillips. It looks like we'll have to agree to disagree on this one.

Comment: @mjwills Suggest an alternative if you think there is one. 90% of my day job is working with json APIs. I've seen the best and worst of them.

Comment: My suggestion is to not put it in a string. :)

Answer (score 0):

`dataset` is a serialized json string. You will need to deserialize this after deserializing the outer object.

```
var jsonresult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var deserializedjsonobject = JObject.Parse(jsonResult);
var Ids = JArray.Parse(deserializedjsonobject["dataset"]);
```

Comment: Ids would be a JArray and not an Array of ids, like OP needs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone input. The issue that I did not pay attention to was that the fact that dataset": "[XXXXX]" was wrapped in double quote and hence was coming back as string. I contacted the provider and they fixed the problem